# Count unique values in excel Columns with blanks

Tags: excel, count, unique, criteria

I have Data in one column (m), the data contains a number of blanks & I want to be able to count the number of unique occurances that begin with the number 2.

Comment: welcome to the stackoverflow, please notice that for asking a good question you should present data,your first attempt and then explain your issue to let the community help you with proper feed back .

Comment: Filter your data to only items that begin with 2, paste that to a new worksheet, remove duplicates on the range. Now you have a list of unique occurrences beginning with 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(M1:M16)="2")/(COUNTIFS(M1:M16,M1:M16)+(M1:M16="")))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott,  many thanks for that.  Works well if I have no blanks, but I will and do have blanks occasionally and they are significant in their own right.  Is there a way of ignoring blank cells to avoid a result of #DIV/0.  RICHARD

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I have many blanks in the data set. I did the whole column with over a million blanks and it ignored them.

Comment: Hi Scott will try again, but got #div/0 errors

Comment: Scott tried again and works, missed a bracket. Doh.  Many thanks sir.

Comment: Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.